# Diseases Wreaking Havoc With Peppers Should I Discard Them?

Tags: diseases, peppers

This post has multiple questions inside that I really need help with identifying what's wrong with the plants and should I remove them, if so, which ones.

I'm also curious if any of those issues could transmit to tomatoes, figs, bananas and cucumbers in particular.

Location: Memphis/TN, grow-zone: 7-b, weather: inhabitable/uphill battle.

I have 2 sets of hydroponic peppers outside in the patio with a couple pot planted peppers. I know the diseases aren't from the seeds since the peppers inside are doing just fine but sadly I only have 2 plants inside the tent.

One disease manifests with making the entire leave to lose color and turn into a weird mixture of brown & yellow with small green specs. Here are the pictures of those:

When the disease is advancing:

[image: This is when the disease is advancing]

And it eventually killed one of the small plants as such:

[image]

**Question is** Should I remove these or I could apply some sort of fungicide / hydrogen peroxide? Would there be a possible way to save the ones that still have green set of leaves? If so, do I need to **remove all** or just removing the obviously infected ones and **treating the rest** with whatever solution available out there is fine?

Other disease is I'm assuming *mild mottle*, I'm attaching the picture just to confirm if I'm right or not (this is also a hydroponic plant that I moved to different spot to prevent contact with ghost peppers)

**Question #2** is: Is this mild mottle and if so, should I discard this or there's a way to save it?

[image]

Following are the same species of peppers with the one above.

**Question #3** is: does the following plant seem to have mild mottle? Do I need to remove these? Is there a way to save this?

[image]

And finally I have the mad hatter, I thought it had some sort of fungus when the leaves started to have yellow dots and I applied copper/seranade mix with the same ratio I apply to tomatoes. It seems to have made the plant worse and now the disease seems to have spread into much more leaves than it was.

Question #4 is:How can I identify what this is and if it's bacterial, viral or 
fungal?

[image: mad hatter #1]

[image: mad hatter #2]

Sorry for asking this many questions in one post but I thought it may be relevant to each-other, particularly if I need to remove all these plants... Hopefully I could get some sort of an answer from here before I cause damage to the garden.

Comment: Have your ever fertilized with a balanced fertilizer of N P K?  Plants that are weak because they are unable to make food for themselves are vulnerable to virus, fungus and insects.  I see at least two.  Where is your garden?  Where are these starts being grown?  What kind of light?  Are you acclimating your starts to the out of doors before putting them out of doors?  What are those green tub things?

Comment: @stormy those are peppers in hydroponic tubs, one tub has 4-18-38 Master Blend, the other tub has General Hydroponics 3 part formula. I usually have my hydroponics in my garage but this year the garage AC wasn't functioning well so I decided to try some in the patio.
The potted peppers, I use Miracle Gro Performance water soluble once a week 1 tablespoon per 5 gallon of water. I soak the soil with it, they usually take 6-8 ounces each, max.

Comment: I've been looking up THRIPS.  This could very well be your problem. https://www.almanac.com/pest/thrips   Your plants look on the verge of being OVER fertilized so I would cut back to half of what you are doing.  Over fertilized plants attract sucking insects like crazy.  I would, myself, get rid of all of those plants and start again, once we learn what the heck happened.  You will have to bleach those bins, perhaps even fog the environments these plants have been in.  Those rocks look 'suspicious'.  Were they sterile before you used them?  What are those called?

Comment: @stormy The rocks are just pebbles that I buy in large bags, and I always use them in my hydroponics, I have the pebbles from the same bag in my veggies inside and I'm certain that they are doing perfect. 
Over-fertilization argument made me think that the weather actually has been over 95 degrees for a very long time and that might have made the water evaporate faster and throw my calculations of how much nutrition I'm adding to the solution. Would you be certain that the img #1 and #2 are related to overnutrition? If so, would it be recoverable?
And yes, I do have thrips unfortunately.

Comment: What I am seeing is 'too green' leaves.  Not a big deal right now at all. The temperatures over 95 degrees (Fahrenheit?) would be a very good culprit.  Plants are unable to handle temperatures over 85 degrees F.  Stress to the max.  High temperatures mean low to no fertilizer.  Plants stop photosynthesizing at these temperatures so fertilizer could build up and cause problem.  The rocks aren't sterilized.  Everything in hydroponics needs to be sterilized.  You can see that just ONE virus, ONE disease would infect all of your plants.  I think your idea of over fertilization is on track.  Thrips

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41545-018-0019-5  The human feces is an interesting part of this disease.

Comment: @stormy I never thought about sterilizing everything, thanks for that tip, I have been growing hydroponic plants for 3-4 years but maybe this time I hit the lottery in contamination. 
The article you sent convinced me to discard the entire tub rather than individual plants but water is the only on-par thing with Memphis, we have literally the "perfect" water for hydroponics, and I doubt human feces could be an issue unless the neighbor is doing her business in my yard. Also water one common variable of sick and healthy plants so it can't be the issue. 
So you think I'm right in mild mottle?

Comment: I've seem to have had 'mild mottle' on a set of Cosumel Peppers.  Didn't stop them from producing I kid you not.  They actually have an infestation of spider mite...because the plant was 'sick'?

Comment: Do you have some land outside your home to grow stuff?  Or did you start! with hydroponics?  If you are able I would definitely try growing in soil as well.  Being a gardener is not some easy thing!  Once you learn the basics you can prevent problems in the future.  You know an awful lot, Return.  Do you live in the States?  If so, you just have to look up your nearest host University Cooperative Extension Service.  Learning the basics within a month, month and 1/2 is phenomenal.  They offer Master gardener, Master Pruner, Composter, Pesticide applicator, Food Preserver courses, testing.

Comment: @stormy great idea! Yes, I'm in Memphis/TN working as a software engineer, so very open to further education by trade :) I deal with hydroponics for 3+ years, successfully grown tomatoes, cucumbers, lettuce and peppers over the years but this is the first time I tried outdoor gardening and I'm learning how hard it is. I didn't even know how to deal with the wind and rain frankly, let alone humidity, aphids, light, soil chemistry... Indoor hydroponics is much easier other than pollination and the electricity costs but it works like a charm. I have a huge yard that I'll be gardening next year.

Comment: That is a unique view: Hydroponics being 'easier' than the soil stuff.  I can see that happening.  Grins, I don't do have never done probably will never do hydroponics only because I know the soil way.  Hydroponics is foreign to me.  You are a righteous gardener.  I'd love to know how hydroponics will help you dealing with the soil gardening.  Just keep asking questions. A few books you must have; The Cannabis Encyclopedia by Jorge Cervantes  (excellent detail and applicable to all plants), speaks your language of hydroponics.  The Vegetable Gardener's Bible by Ed C. Smith.

Comment: @stormy I really think anyone who started gardening with indoor hydroponics will think the same as we get so used to controlling the light, heat, bugs (there's no triphs problem inside for example and aphids are very unlikely to get into your tent.) I noticed I staked my tomatoes with bamboo sticks and they will likely to be broken with a mild wind very soon. Outdoor gardening is spontaneous. And of course, it doesn't rain indoors, so you don't have to deal with blight etc.
Hard thing about the hydroponics is staking and pollinating and that's pretty much it. Thanks for the recommendations.